# Redirect query to search results API Flask

Tags: html, flask

I have three pages on a website

1. Search Page: User enters a search string and results are fetched from an API
2. Image Gallery: Random Images fetched from the same API along with image titles
3. Results Page: Displays Results from the search page

How do I redirect to the results page by using 'image titles' as the search query to be passed to the API

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stackoverflow.

You can provide the html that you want to show to end user when particular API in accessed.
For example:

```
@app.route('/search', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def search():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        search_query = request.form['search_query']
        """do something"""
    return render_template('result.html')
```

In above example, when search URL is accessed by end user, the flask app will return `result.html` page which will contain the results from search results.